# kworker has high CPU usage on idle system

Tags: raspberry-pi, cpu-usage

Thanks for stopping by!

So I just bought a [Pi desktop kit](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-83477/l/desktop-computer-kit-with-expansion-board-that-can-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-real-desktop-pc) for my RaspberryPi 3B v1.2, which features an add-on module with an mSATA disk slot, real-time clock and power control. I installed the latest raspbian stretch (kernel version 4.9.59-v7+) on the mSATA SSD, and are now booting Raspbian from it with no SD card in the onboard card reader.

A kworker process is now constantly hogging between 8.0-13.5% CPU usage, which I think seems quite unnecessary, and it has annoying consequences, fx lagging videos with Kodi. This has never happened before I added the module.

[image: kworker has high CPU usage as observed with top]

I then tried `perf` (inspiration from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/422151)) by running `sudo perf record -D 1000 -g -a sleep 20` and then `sudo perf report` to figure out which kernel tasks might be responsible:

[image: sudo perf record -D 1000 -g -a sleep 20]

But I can't figure out how to go on from there to reduce the workload. Could it be caused by the real-time clock embedded in the add-on board as `__timer_delay`, `arch_timer_read_counter_long`, and `arch_counter_get_cntpct` seem to have a high CPU usage? Other tasks with high load are `finish_task_switch` and `_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore` tasks, but I can't guess what that's about.

Am I right that this is unnecessary work load of the CPU and if so, how can I reduce it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the root cause was that I didn't insert SD card into my Raspberry Pi. When SD card is missing, the kernel frequently tries to scan the SD card slot, which causes high CPU usage.
Download `sdtweak.dtbo` and replace the existing one under `/boot/overlays/` with the new one, then add `dtoverlay=sdtweak,poll_once` into `/boot/config.txt` and reboot the machine. It worked for me.

See also: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2567

Comment: Seems to have worked -- kworker no longer showing up with constant ~10% CPU usage. Many thanks! Very odd that this started happening for no apparent cause (no shut down etc. that I was aware of). Note to others: You probably don't need to download `sdtweak.dtbo` if your rpi device was setup recently since the firmware will be up to date with the ability to accept `dtoverlay=sdtweak,poll_once` in `/boot/config.txt `

Answer (score 0):

You can install iotop for looking at load.

For high load /etc/sysctl.conf :

vm.vfs_cache_pressure=500

vm.swappiness=10

vm.dirty_background_ratio=1

vm.dirty_ratio=50

#### then sysctl --system